# What does "hold benefits, vigils, and fundraisers" mean in this sentence? Is "benefits" different from "fundraisers"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Amnesty members continue to tirelessly write letters and **hold benefits, vigils, and fundraisers** for prisoners of conscience around the world.

What is the deference between "hold benefits" and "hold fundraisers"? Does both mean to hold events for collecting money in favour of prisoners?

Comment: I do think that having both **benefit** and **fundraiser** is redundant since they are very close in meaning.  **Benefit** has a stronger connotation of there being a party or dinner, but that just makes it a subset of **fundraiser**.  There is a principle in writing called the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(writing)) that says that a list of three examples is more satisfying to the reader than a list of any other size.  Perhaps the writer was stretching to get three examples and had to essentially duplicate one with two different words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A benefit is a type of fundraiser. Perhaps the speaker should have said:

> Amnesty members continue to tirelessly write letters and hold
>   benefits, vigils, and **other** fundraisers for prisoners of
>   conscience around the world.